# SQL. Locating gaps between a series of fromDates and toDates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data in an Oracle table as follows:

```
ROW    USERNAME DATEFROM    DATETO
1      User01   15/03/2020  17/06/2020
2      User01   18/06/2020  21/05/2021
3      User01   22/05/2021  12/08/2021
4      User02   27/07/2021  14/09/2021
5      User02   20/09/2021  15/12/2021 --Offending row.
```

I have included the Row ID in this example for clarity. In my real table, there is no sequential rowID. I'm looking for rows having gaps from DateFrom to DateTo across records. In the above data, for example, RowID 2 is OK because DateFrom is 18/06/2020 which is the next day from DateTo in row  1. The error is in row 5 because there is a gap between DateTo in row 4 and DateFrom in row 5. DateFrom in row 5 should have been 15/09/2021 to be correct.
I need an SQL script to locate all the gaps in a table of several thousand records.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the earliest row in your table, the below query should select everything that does not immediately follow another date.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE DATEFROM - 1 NOT IN (SELECT DATETO FROM Table)
```

Comment: I don't think so; did you test it? It returns 3 rows (based on sample data Chris posted), while there's only one offending row. Besides, your logic isn't what Chris described.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (username, datefrom, dateto) as
  2    (select 'user1', date '2020-03-15', date '2020-06-17' from dual union all
  3     select 'user1', date '2020-06-18', date '2021-05-21' from dual union all
  4     select 'user1', date '2021-05-22', date '2021-08-12' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 'user2', date '2021-07-27', date '2021-09-14' from dual union all
  7     select 'user2', date '2021-09-20', date '2021-12-15' from dual
  8    ),
```

Query begins here; the `temp` CTE "calculates" the next `DATEFROM` using the `LEAD` analytic function. The final query then fetches mismatched rows:

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select username, datefrom, dateto,
 11       lead(datefrom) over (partition by username order by datefrom) next_datefrom
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  select username, datefrom, dateto
 15  from temp
 16  where next_datefrom <> dateto + 1;

USERN DATEFROM   DATETO
----- ---------- ----------
user2 27/07/2021 14/09/2021

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is there a way to make this work without the 'dual union all' statements? This code is not accepted either in my environment (Oracle HCM) or in any online editor I tried. I tried creating the test table, populating it with data and running your script from line 9 downwards in mycompiler.io/new/sql editor but it returned wrong results.

Comment: "Sample data" represent exactly that - sample data. You should have those rows in your table already. Code you should run begins with the WITH keyword, and then the rest of code I posted from line #9 (so: `with temp as ...`. I don't know why it returned "wrong results" for you, because it returns correct results for me (as demonstrated).

Comment: I'm creating the test table.
Inserting the values.
Running the query:
with temp as
   (select username, datefrom, dateto,
   ...
and I'm getting the following results:
User01|15/03/2020|17/06/2020
User01|18/06/2020|21/05/2021
User02|20/09/2021|15/12/2021

I don't doubt that it's working for you. I'm just trying to figure out why it's not working for me.
Note that I'm in a restricted environment where I'm only allowed to make select statements and I'm having a hard time finding a proper Oracle testing environment online.
Perhaps sharing which environment/tool you are using? Thanks

Comment: I ran that code in Oracle 21XE database installed on my laptop, using SQL*Plus as a tool.